# Truss rod adjustments and tuning

Tags: tuning, maintenance

I'm setting up my guitar and I am about to adjust my truss rod. I heard to tune the guitar first but what tuning? I typically play tuned down a step and a half. Should I tune my guitar to that setting or standard E?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you will only play that guitar with that gauge of strings in that tuning, then that's what you do.Tune up to standard, and adjust,and the truss rod will wonder what the heck's happened when you tune down!